# Is dp (Density-independent Pixels) a Physical Size?

Tags: android, css

According the definition of dp:

> Density-independent Pixels - an abstract unit that is based on the physical density of the screen. These units are relative to a 160 dpi screen, so one dp is one pixel on a 160 dpi screen

We can calculate that `1dp = 1/160` inch, which is a physical size.

However `dp` seems not considered as a physical size like the table below,

this table is from answer of [What is the difference between “px”, “dip”, “dp” and “sp”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/10139109)

```
| Unit    | Description | Units Per     | Density     | Same Physical Size | 
|         |             | Physical Inch | Independent | On Every Screen    | 
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+
| px      | Pixels      | Varies        | No          | No                 | 
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+
| in      | Inches      | 1             | Yes         | Yes                | 
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+
| mm      | Millimeters | 25.4          | Yes         | Yes                | 
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+
| pt      | Points      | 72            | Yes         | Yes                | 
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+
| dp      | Density     | ~160          | Yes         | No                 | 
|         | Independent |               |             |                    | 
|         | Pixels      |               |             |                    | 
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+
| sp      | Scale       | ~160          | Yes         | No                 | 
|         | Independent |               |             |                    | 
|         | Pixels      |               |             |                    | 
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

So, yes or no.

If no, why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Question!.

When they say physical size, they mean the physical number of pixels.

Since a high resolution screen has more pixels per inch then a low resolution screen. The physical number of pixels per dp will be less on the lower resolution screen.

That being said, most phone screens do not fit in perfectly into any bucket. What happens then is that android fits them into the closest bucket which can cause the number of pixel per dp to stray from the bucket amount.